# Two Python Interpreters

Tags: python, version, interpreter

I just installed Python 3.X Interpreter, but various libraries still need Python 2.X, and I wonder if I can have installed two python interpreters and if it would become a problem later when trying to execute some script.

Thank you.

Comment: You may have a look at http://www.virtualenv.org/

Answer (score 0):

You can have both python 3.x and 2.x installed. The interpreter used will depend on how you execute your scripts.

Using python3

```
python3 test.py
```

Using python2

```
python test.py
```